# Fork a Pull request, on Github

Tags: github

What is the right workflow for effectively forking a Pull request?

To explain the use case: I've found a repository which contains a pull request that adds a feature I need. Unfortunately the pull request author has gone awol and the repo owner won't accept the pull request until tests are written. I'd like to "fork" the Pull request and write tests so that the repo owner will accept the new functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fork the original project, write the unit tests, then use the "Fork Queue" feature to selectively incorporate the changes by the third party into your own repository, and finally issue a pull request to your own repository, unit tests inclusive, to the original repository.

Comment: Awesome solution, I didn't know about that feature. Unfortunately the original pull request does not apply cleanly to the current repo (so says the fork queue tool).

Comment: You can do the "fork tool" manually, too: Add the third-party repo with `git remote add`, and then you can merge files and compare with and merge from the other repo with your usual git tools...

Comment: What do we do now there is no fork queue on github?