# Github : Fork with pull requests

Tags: github

I am working on this code : https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

This have many pull request pending. But due to some reason Author is not able to accept.

So I decide to Fork project and accept some of the request which can improve code.

But when I [fork project](https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/SVPullToRefresh) I don't get all that Pull request in Forked copy.

Is there any way to get that all pull request in my forked copy?

I Get this question which is very similar : [Fork a Pull request, on Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296536/fork-a-pull-request-on-github)

But I am not able to know how to do it. I am not able to find how to write "unit tests".

I get some answer which require to get local copy on my computer and than work with some git commands. But I think there should some way to do it on web interface only. Tell me if I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be to see the PR from the original "`upstream`" repo in your fork, but you still can import them in your local clone:

```
git remote add upstream /url/of/original/repo
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*"
```

(The `pull/ID` branch naming convention is mentioned in the GitHub help page "[Modifying an inactive pull request locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally)")

That way, you can merge any `upstream/pr/<ID>` branch you want in your local repo.

Comment: It means I have to clone repository on my Machine. Am I right?

Comment: @CRDave yes, in order to import the PR branches of the original repo. A fully remote GUI management of the PR isn't directly possible on the GitHub web site for your fork. A local clone is needed.

Comment: OK I will try and come to you.